# How to make a recomandation machine learning with ML.NET with a tag property

Tags: c#, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, recommendation-engine, ml.net

For my project I would like to integrate a recomendation system. my dataset looks like this.

```
userId, projectId, projectCategory
1,1, API
1,5, Database
2,6, Arduino
```

Each user joins a project with a specific tag. I would like to recommend projects to my users based on the projects they join. Could I do machine learning based on the tags.

Answer (score 0):

How is the ProjectId different than the tag? At first glance, I would assume the ProjectId implies some information about the category. Users who like certain project ids (which I assume belong to a category) are most likely to like similar project ids. I would encourage you to check out this tutorial which shows how to use ML.NET Model Builder to train a recommendation model using data similar to the one you have.

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/movie-recommendation-model-builder